# Using a variable in xpath in Python Selenium

Tags: python, variables, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been having trouble figuring out how to get a variable to work Selenium. This post seems to have helped ([Variable not working inside parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034207/variable-not-working-inside-parenthesis)) but I still can't get it to work.

When I used the actual value it works. In this case AL-Alabama. I created a variable called state so that I can just call
that in my function. I have 13 states to run through.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='AL-Alabama']").click()
```

This one uses the state variable and in looking at error message it shows the variable value as AL-Alabama. So it seems like
it's referencing the correct value in the web page. Not sure what I'm missing or why it's not working. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[@value=' + state + ']').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//option[@value=AL-Alabama]"}
```

Comment: I marked the post by @EGHM as the answer. But for those who may be able to use this information I did find that Select also does indeed work. I used     Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("c3")).select_by_visible_text(state). Not sure if I was supposed to put code in a comment.

Comment: @shavar going with a Select abstraction is indeed a much cleaner way to approach the problem.

Comment: @ alecxe I appreciate your input. I was curious if Select was the preferred method. Going forward where possible I'll use Select abstraction. I'll have to do a bit more reading on its use of course.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The single quotes around the value are not present with how you coded it.  Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='" + state + "']").click()
```

Comment: Yep that did it. So I guess it wasn't reading it as a string? This will help me with my other projects. Thank you.

Comment: I think python was reading it as a string.  I know from lots of experience those quotes around values after the equals sign are required by Selenium.

Comment: Super-helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To `click()` on the element with respect to the variable *value* attribute of the `<option>` tag using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using variable in `XPATH`:

  ```
  state = 'AL-Alabama'
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='" +state+ "']").click()
  ```
- Using `%s` in `XPATH`:

  ```
  state = 'AL-Alabama'
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='%s']"% str(state)).click()
  ```
- Using `format()` in `XPATH`:

  ```
  state = 'AL-Alabama'
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='{}']".format(str(state))).click()
  ```

---

### Best Practices

Ideally. to `click()` on the element with respect to the variable *value* attribute of the `<option>` tag using *Selenium]* and you need to to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using variable in `XPATH`:

  ```
  state = 'AL-Alabama'
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//option[@value='" +state+ "']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `%s` in `XPATH`:

  ```
  state = 'AL-Alabama'
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//option[@value='%s']"% str(state)))).click()
  ```
- Using `format()` in `XPATH`:

  ```
  state = 'AL-Alabama'
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//option[@value='{}']".format(str(state))))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to find an element with respect to the user input using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188981/how-to-find-an-element-with-respect-to-the-user-input-using-selenium-and-python/62189841#62189841)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use single quotes then you can also try this answer. Check if it helps:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[@value=\'{State_Name}\']'.format(State_Name=State)).click()
```

or simply

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[@value=\'{}\']'.format(State)).click()
```

You can pass "State" as parameter in your function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to use the format string "f" and add the variable_name in {}     `driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//List[@AutomationId=\"TileGridView\"]//ListItem[@ClassName=\"GridViewItem\"][@Name=\"{variable_name}\"]....")`