# How to find an element with respect to the user input using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The following is the HTML structure:

```
<div class='list'>
  <div>
    <p class='code'>12345</p>
    <p class='name'>abc</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class='code'>23456</p>
    <p class='name'>bcd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And there is a config.py for user input. If the user input 23456 to config.code, how can the selenium python select the second object? I am using `find_by_css_selector()` to locate and select the object, but it can only select the first object, which is *Code='12345'*. I tried to use `find_by_link_text()`, but it is a `<p>` element not `<a>` element. Anyone can help.....

Comment: By second object do you mean the <p class='name'> element?

Comment: @LoganGeorge No. One div means one object, I want to select the second object which code is 23456 and name is bcd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element with respect to the input by the user using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you need to to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using variable in `XPATH`:

  ```
  user_input = '23456'
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list']//div/p[@class='code' and text()='" +user_input+ "']")))
  ```
- Using `%s` in `XPATH`:

  ```
  user_input = '23456'
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list']//div/p[@class='code' and text()='%s']"% str(user_input))))
  ```
- Using `format()` in `XPATH`:

  ```
  user_input = '23456'
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list']//div/p[@class='code' and text()='{}']".format(str(user_input)))))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below xpath:

```
code = '23456'
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='code' and text()='" +code +"']")
```

Comment: Right. Then to get the sibling I think it would be driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='code' and text()='" +code +"']/following-sibling::p")

Comment: @frianH it wokrs! But i am not really understand the use of xpath. Can you explain more on "//p[@class='code' and text()='" +code +"']" ?

Comment: @LoganGeorge what's the meaning of sibling u are talking?

Comment: @YukChan that's just simple logic using the `AND` expression. Trying search for a `p` tag with the class name is `code` and the tag has the text `23456`.

Comment: @frianH then how about  '" +code +"'? not really understand this syntax

Comment: @YukChan it's for string merger.