# How to locate an element with respect to a variable within a xpath using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, variables, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
size = '19'

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Sélectionner Taille:" + size]').click()
```

this is my code, but it doesn't work as the ' stuck the variable into a simple quotation 
so I don't know how to do, please help me
I use selenium with python into chrome driver

Answer (score 0):

> try this it will help you.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title="Sélectionner Taille:"'" + size + "']").click()
```

You can also refer to this answer as well: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874539/using-a-variable-in-xpath-in-python-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML it is not clear about the number of white spaces between **Sélectionner Taille:** and **19**. So discounting all the white spaces to invoke `click()` on the element with respect to the variable using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you need to to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using variable in `XPATH`:

  ```
  size = '19'
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@title, 'Sélectionner Taille') and contains(@title, '" +size+ "')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `%s` in `XPATH`:

  ```
  size = '19'
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@title, 'Sélectionner Taille') and contains(@title, '%s')]"% str(size)))).click()
  ```
- Using `format()` in `XPATH`:

  ```
  size = '19'
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@title, 'Sélectionner Taille') and contains(@title, '{}')]".format(str(size))))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to find an element with respect to the user input using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188981/how-to-find-an-element-with-respect-to-the-user-input-using-selenium-and-python/62189841#62189841)